# Convert binary DB2 log files to readable/analyzable format

Tags: logging, db2, cqrs

I have a legacy business system running on a DB2 database. I'd like to analyze the changes that software is making to the database.

Is there any way for me to convert DB2 log files to a format readable and analyzable by another program?

Comment: The answer depends on your DB2 version and platform.

Comment: Sorry! Should have known. DB2 9.6 fix pack 7 on Windows.

Comment: There's no such thing as DB2 9.6 on Windows, sorry.

Comment: Got the numbers mixed up... 9.7 fix pack 6.

Comment: Anyway, on Windows (also Linux and Unix) there is a C language API `db2ReadLogNoConn` that you can use to write your own program. It's described here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0009368.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows (also Linux and Unix) there is a C language API db2ReadLogNoConn that you can use to write your own program. It's described here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0009368.html

Another option is the DB2 Advanced Recovery Feature (http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/db2-advanced-recovery-feature) which is capable of regenerating SQL statements from log records. I've never used it so I can't say if it's suitable for your purposes.

(I'm told to avoid extended discussions in comments so I'll put this as an answer.)